# Ansible with "sudo su - "

Tags: ansible

(There are already a few questions about this, but no solution worked for me)

On the servers I work on, we have to "sudo su - webapps" and then run our commands as webapps.
Ansible does not provide a native way to do this I believe (sudo only is available but the sysadmins restricted the list of commands I can run it with, su is available with Ansible but does not work on its own on the servers).

I've tried
https://www.coveros.com/ansible-privledge-escalation-using-sudo-su/

```
[privilege_escalation]
become_exe=sudo su -
```

With playbook :

```
---
- hosts:
    - test
  become: yes
  become_user: webapps
  become_method: su
  tasks:
  - name: Updates file
    copy:
      src: a.txt
      dest: dest/a.txt
```

Running it gives :

> SSH: EXEC ssh -vvv -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o
>   ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o
>   PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey
>   -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="myUser"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/Users/lmoreau/.ansible/cp/d895b40f7e -tt myServer '/bin/sh -c '"'"'sudo su -  webapps -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'/bin/sh -c
>   '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'echo
>   BECOME-SUCCESS-nxilvumwmfikgyuisutwiwobidrgqpao ; /usr/bin/python
>   /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1583355901.6967812-200466745901442/AnsiballZ_setup.py'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"''"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'
>   && sleep 0'"'"''
>
> ...
>
> "msg": "Timeout (12s) waiting for privilege escalation prompt: \r\nWe
>   trust you have received the usual lecture from the local
>   System\r\nAdministrator. It usually boils down to these three
>   things:\r\n\r\n    #1) Respect the privacy of others.\r\n    #2) Think
>   before you type.\r\n    #3) With great power comes great
>   responsibility.\r\n\r\n"

Alternative attempt with :

```
[privilege_escalation]
become_exe=’sudo su - ‘
```

> "module_stdout": "/bin/sh: ’sudo: command not found\r\n",
>               "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",

Without overriding the become_exe:

- "su" method gives "Timeout (12s) waiting for privilege escalation
  prompt: "
- "sudo" method gives "msg": "Missing sudo password"

Note : I do not have the password of the account I want to become, and am not supposed to have any.

How can I do the same as what I do by hand with Ansible ?

Comment: This is becoming a FAQ: [ansible does not tolerate restricted become commands](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html#privilege-escalation-must-be-general), but you're welcome to try some of the competing [become plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/plugins/become.html#plugin-list) and see if they fit your security requirements any better

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
- hosts: application
  become: yes
  become_exe: "sudo su - webapps"
  become_method: su
  tasks:
```